# Ставить в заголовке статьи тире или нет

Tags: пунктуация

Есть заголовок статьи: "Ритм жизни ощути в Турции!". Человек настаивает на постановке тире после слова "жизни". То есть это будет так: "Ритм жизни - ощути в Турции!". На сайте www.gramota.ru нашла только такое, что хоть как-то, возможно, подходит:

§ 169. Тире ставится между двумя сказуемыми и между двумя независимыми предложениями, если во втором из них содержится неожиданное присоединение или резкое противопоставление по отношению к первому, например:

Я вышел, не желая его обидеть, на террасу – и обомлел. (Герцен)
Я спешу туда ж – а там уже весь город. (Пушкин)
Хотел объехать целый свет – и не объехал сотой доли. (Грибоедов)
Хотел рисовать – кисти выпадали из рук. Пробовал читать – взоры его скользили над строками. (Лермонтов)

Примечание 1. Для усиления оттенка неожиданности тире может ставиться после сочинительных союзов, связывающих две части одного предложения, например:

Проси в субботу расчет и – марш в деревню. (М. Горький)
Очень хочется сойти туда к ним, познакомиться, но – боюсь. (М. Горький)

Примечание 2. Для выражения неожиданности может отделяться посредством тире любая часть предложения, например:

И щуку бросили – в реку. (Крылов)
И съела бедного певца – до крошки. (Крылов)

Оправдывает ли данное правило постановку тире в заголовке статьи? Моё мнение - нет. А Человек настаивает, что знак препинания "тире" обязательно должен стоять. Кто же из нас прав. Помогите разобраться.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Знаки препинания в газетных и журнальных заголовках

В газетных и журнальных заголовках, с их многообразными функциями (номинативной, информативной, рекламно-экспрессивной, побудительно-убеждающей, графически-выделительной), используются почти все знаки русской пунктуации. Укажем важнейшее из них.
Тире

1. Тире ставится в эллиптических предложениях-заголовках, построенных по формуле "кому-чему — что" или «"что — кому— чему" (см. § 6, п. 3): Выпускнику — профессию; Новому — широкую дорогу; Транспорту — чёткость и слаженность; Достижения науки — в производство; Имя Гагарина — малой планете; Награды — лучшим; Музыка — детям.
2. Тире ставится в двучленных предложениях-заголовках, построенных по формулам "кто — чему", "кто — куда", "что — куда" «"что — где", "что — как", "что — для чего'' и т. д. (см. § 6, п. 4): Учёные — производству; Клоуны — на арену; Книгу — в массы; Передовую технологию — в производство; Учителя — в отпуске; Ракета — на орбите; Строить — быстро.

Ср. заголовки другой структуры: Задание десяти месяцев — выполнено; В город — на праздник книги; За опытом — к соседям; В час — тысяча саженцев; На линии — 115 городов; Главные задачи — впереди; По ступеням — к высотам знаний; За преступление — к ответу.

1. Тире ставится в заголовках, построенных по схеме «подлежащее — сказуемое» без связки (что отвечает об щей норме; см. § 5, п. 1): Герои фильмов — дети; Курс — интенсификация; Автор — студент; Девиз соревнований — скорость; Технические средства — помощники учителя.
2. Тире ставится в заголовках, состоящих из нескольких форм именительного падежа (номинативов): Зима — снег — лыжи; Школа — жизнь — труд.   Подписка
       Получать список новых книг
       Список книг и рецензий
   Регистрация

   > ***Справочник по русскому языку. Пунктуация*** Розенталь.Д.Э.

Из приведенных пунктов, подходит пункт " Заголовки другой структуры", на основании которого в приведенном вами предложении можно поставить тире. Но должен согласится с Верой, что само предложение для рекламного заголовка построено не совсем удачно. Заголовок должен быть экспрессивно-эмоциональным. Можно переделать его, как предложила Вера, и тогда сомнение о постановке тире отпадает.

Comment: Спасибо, узнала много нового. Процитирую Вас: "...Но должен согласится с Верой, что само предложение для рекламного заголовка построено не совсем удачно. Заголовок должен быть экспрессивно-эмоциональным. Можно переделать его, как предложила Вера, и тогда сомнение о постановке тире отпадает." АБСОЛЮТНО СОГЛАСНА! Поэтому тире всё-же из заголовка статьи было убрано.

Answer (score 4):

Думаю, что тире здесь  не ставится даже в авторском варианте, так как невозможно сделать паузу при чтении.

Если есть желание изменить название, сделать его более эмоциональным, экспрессивным, то можно предложить такой вариант (с тире или двоеточием): "Ритм жизни - ощути его в Турции!".

Comment: Спасибо, именно так и хотели написать, но клиент отказался, сказав, что добавлять слова в заголовок нельзя. Ваш аргумент, надеюсь, пригодится.

Comment: 
Vera: Думаю, что тире здесь не ставится даже в авторском варианте, так как невозможно сделать паузу при чтении.=== Почему же невозможно? Возможно! Когда-то в одной из реклам для обозначения  паузы в этом предложении было использовано многоточие:
"Ритм жизни… ощути в Турции!" (ссылку см. ниже).

Comment: https://books.google.ru/books?id=D7O6jELubHUC&pg=PA169&dq=%22%D0%A0%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC+%D0%B6%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B8+%D0%BE%D1%89%D1%83%D1%82%D0%B8+%D0%B2+%D0%A2%D1%83%D1%80%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8!%22&hl=ru&sa=X&ei=aQPQVLv9NoOdygO3koCgCg&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22%D0%A0%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC%20%D0%B6%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B8%20%D0%BE%D1%89%D1%83%D1%82%D0%B8%20%D0%B2%20%D0%A2%D1%83%D1%80%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8!%22&f=false

Comment: Думаю, что это первые образцы, где заглавию (не слишком удачно) пытаются придать особую выразительность. Непонятно, что обозначает такая пауза, обозначенная многоточием. Если это все тот же именительный темы, то оформление несоответствующее.