# Пунктуация в заголовках типа "тема и подтема"

Tags: пунктуация

Примеры названий (заголовков), тип которых я обозначил как "тема и подтема":

**РУСИСТИКА – ВЧЕРА, СЕГОДНЯ, ЗАВТРА** (Конференция)

**Ленин: вчера, сегодня, завтра** (Блог)

**Русские пословицы. Толкование и примеры употребления** (Книга)

**Распространенный причастный оборот в начале предложения — нужна ли запятая?** 
(Вопрос на нашем сайте)

**“Представить”: индикатив или сослагательное наклонение?** (Вопрос на нашем сайте).

Какими правилами нужно руководствоваться, выбирая знаки препинания в подобных случаях?

Comment: Возможный повтор вопроса. https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/46781/%d0%a1%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b2-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%b3%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%ba%d0%b5-%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c%d0%b8-%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%b5-%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%82

Comment: Скорее повтор ответа

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Розенталь пишет: "Знаки препинания в газетных и журнальных заголовках. Не говоря уже о том, что в заголовках используются почти все знаки препинания (а это само по себе представляет интерес в плане оптимального их отбора), следует отметить варианты пунктуационного оформления одинаковых конструкций; ср.: Профессия: репортёр и Профессия — репортёр. Или еще пример: Знаки препинания… зачем они?; Знаки препинания. Зачем они?; Знаки препинания — зачем они?; Знаки препинания… Зачем они?"

http://www.old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=168

> РУСИСТИКА – ВЧЕРА, СЕГОДНЯ, ЗАВТРА (что - когда)

2. Тире ставится в двучленных предложениях-заголовках, построенных по формулам «кто — чему», «кто — куда», «что — куда», «что — где», «что — как», «что — для чего» и т. д. (см. § 6, п. 4)У нас по типу "что - когда"

> Ленин: вчера, сегодня, завтра

Двоеточие ставится в заголовках, распадающихся на две части с четким интонационным делением, отличающиеся смысловой насыщенностью, предельной краткостью, нередко и эмоциональной выразительностью. Первая часть называет общую проблему, место действия, лицо, а вторая — содержит конкретизацию названного в первой части:Экономическая реформа: опыт, проблемы, трудности; Разоружение: концепция, проблемы, механизм; Россия — Западная Европа: выгоды и перспективы сотрудничества.

> Русские пословицы. Толкование и примеры употребления

Здесь тоже общая проблема и её конкретизация, можно было поставить двоеточие, но автор счёл возможным разделить заголовок на два сегмента. Это тоже возможно:

Точка ставится в сегментированных  и парцеллированных заголовках (см. § 1, п. 4)

> Распространенный причастный оборот в начале предложения — нужна ли запятая?

Сегментированный заголовок,по правилам нужна бы точка, но автор счёл его синонимичным формуле "что - как".Видимо, тоже возможно.

> “Представить”: индикатив или сослагательное наклонение?

Я бы поставила тире,здесь явно тире между подлежащим и сказуемым. Возможна и точка - сегментированное название.Но автор увидел общую тему и её конкретизацию. Кавычки говорят о том, что это словоформа (правда, мы уже обговаривали предпочтительное выделение курсивом). Словоформа и какая проблема есть в этой теме.Тоже вариант.

Comment: Людмила,а почему в двух аналогичных предложениях вы ставите разные знаки препинания?

Comment: РУСИСТИКА – ВЧЕРА, СЕГОДНЯ, ЗАВТРА -это двучленные? Я бы поставил двоеточие здесь.

Comment: Серж, это как раз и есть те самые " варианты пунктуационного оформления одинаковых конструкций; ср.: Профессия: репортёр и Профессия — репортёр. Или еще пример: Знаки препинания… зачем они?; Знаки препинания. Зачем они?; Знаки препинания — зачем они?; Знаки препинания… Зачем они?", о которых пишет Розенталь. В газетных заголовках всё принимается, что возможно объяснить. Это - возможно.

Comment: А где у Розенталя говорится о вариантах пунктуационного оформления?

Comment: В предисловии к пунктуации http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php, цитату я привела в начале ответа

Answer (score 0):

Ответ справочной службы русского языка (Грамота.ру) на похожий вопрос:

> [Вопрос № 295693](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=295693)
>   Уважаемая Грамота! Подскажи, пожалуйста, верно ли ставить тире в предложении "Эпиляция - как навсегда избавиться от нежелательных волос"? Это заголовок статьи в интернете. И если тире верно, то на основании какого правила?
>   **Ответ справочной службы русского языка**
>   В данном случае слово эпиляция выступает в роли именительного темы. По правилам в такой конструкции можно поставить либо точку, либо двоеточие: Эпиляция. Как навсегда избавиться от нежелательных волос и Эпиляция: как навсегда избавиться от нежелательных волос. Тире стоит неверно.